# Email to create a Lead

Tags: email, email2lead

I tried this code but it didn't work. It dump to unresolved items in salesforce. Someone would like to help me on this? appreciated in advance.

```
global class PopulateLeadByEmail implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
  global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.inboundEmail email, 
                                                       Messaging.InboundEnvelope env){
    // Create an InboundEmailResult object for returning the result of the  
    // Apex Email Service 
    Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();
    String myPlainText= '';

    // Add the email plain text into the local variable  
    myPlainText = email.plainTextBody;

    // Check for existing leads with this email address   
    Lead[] leads = [SELECT Id, Name, Email
      FROM Lead
      WHERE Email = :email.fromAddress];

    if (leads.size() == 0) {
      // New Lead object to be created - set LastName and Company to
      // dummy values for simplicity
      Lead newLead = new Lead(Email = email.fromAddress, 
        LastName = email.  , 
        Company = 'From Email');

      // Insert a new lead
      insert newLead;    

      System.debug('New Lead record: ' + newLead );   
    } else {
      System.debug('Incoming email duplicates existing Lead record(s): ' + leads );    
    }

    // Set the result to true. No need to send an email back to the user      
    // with an error message   
    result.success = true;

    // Return the result for the Apex Email Service 
    return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old one, but I figured I would respond anyways!

The issue is you you're not creating a task or an EmailMessage record. If you do the latter, you have to create an EmailMessageRelation with a RelationId pointing to your lead. If you're creating a task, then you'll need to point the WhoId to the lead.

You will need to manually transfer over the data from the inbound email to the EmailMessage

```
        public EmailMessage createEmailMessageFromInbound(Messaging.InboundEmail email) {
            EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage();

            message.FromAddress = email.fromAddress;
            message.FromName = email.fromName;
            message.HtmlBody = email.htmlBody;
            message.TextBody = email.plainTextBody;
            message.Incoming = true;
            message.Subject = email.subject;
            return message;
       }
```

Important note, you have to create the email message with a status of '5' (draft) first, then insert your EmailMessageRelation records. Once you do that, set the email message to a status of '0' or whichever you like.

Further Reading
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm